# Buildozer build error that seems to do with some ant file

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I tried running buildozer using VM on my Windows computer. I used python 3 so I got python3crystax downloaded. I tried packaging the app with the usual 'buildozer android debug' command. Everything was fine until I received the log below. Can someone tell me what went wrong and how I can fix it?

```
-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/classes
      [dex] Found modified input file
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/classes.dex...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/res
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/res/drawable/icon.png => /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/res/drawable/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/res/drawable/icon.png: 49% size of source)
   [crunch] Crunched 1 PNG files to update cache
   [crunch] /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/res/drawable/icon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitkeep' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]       Unable to add '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/assets/private.mp3': Zip add failed (-2147483648)
     [aapt] ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/LearningTheoryGame-1.0.ap_'
     [aapt] ERROR: packaging of '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/LearningTheoryGame-1.0.ap_' failed

BUILD FAILED
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:950: null returned: 1

Total time: 31 seconds


  STDERR:


[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 94):
    -crunch:    
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/res    
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/res   
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/res/drawable/icon.png => /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/res/drawable/icon.png   
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/res/drawable/icon.png: 49% size of source)  
   [crunch] Crunched 1 PNG files to update cache    
   [crunch] /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/res/drawable/icon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited  

-package-resources: 
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...   
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitkeep' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')  
     [aapt]       Unable to add '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/assets/private.mp3': Zip add failed (-2147483648)    
 [aapt] ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/LearningTheoryGame-1.0.ap_'  
 [aapt] ERROR: packaging of '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/bin/LearningTheoryGame-1.0.ap_' failed   

BUILD FAILED    
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:  
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:950: null returned: 1 

Total time: 31 seconds
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory && /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant debug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant failed!
Could not find hostpython, will not compile to .pyo (this is normal with python3)
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No compiled python is present to zip, skipping.
this should only be the case if you are using the CrystaX python
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name learningtheory --name 'Learning Theory Game' --version 1.0 --package com.mydomain.learningtheory --android_api 19 --sdk 19 --minsdk 9 --private /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/app --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

So the above happened and stopped building process. Also another thing I noticed in the logs were the lines below with lots of warnings, although these lines didn't stop the process of building (these lines appeared earlier in the sequence). Perhaps there's something I'm missing here as well?

```
# Package the application
# project.properties updated
# Run "/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name learningtheory --name 'Learning Theory Game' --version 1.0 --package com.mydomain.learningtheory --android_api 19 --sdk 19 --minsdk 9 --private /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/app --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
# Cwd /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Getting Android API version from user argument
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[WARNING]: NDK version was set as r9c, but checking the NDK dir claims it is 10.3.2.
[WARNING]: The build will try to continue, but it may fail and you should check that your setting is correct.
[WARNING]: If the NDK dir result is correct, you don't need to manually set the NDK ver.
[INFO]:    Using Crystax NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9', '5', 'clang3.6', 'clang3.7']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 5
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     learningtheory: includes recipes (hostpython3crystax, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python3crystax, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    learningtheory has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     learningtheory: includes recipes (hostpython3crystax, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python3crystax, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    learningtheory has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory
[DEBUG]:   -> running ant debug
[DEBUG]:    Buildfile: /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/learningtheory/build.xml
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -set-mode-check:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -set-debug-files:
```

UPDATE: BUILDOZER FILE
Below is the buildozer.spec file that I used when running the buildozer

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Learning Theory Game

# (str) Package name
package.name = learningtheory

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.mydomain

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,gif

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3crystax, kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path = ~

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = /build/myapp

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: Don't worry about the warnings. I have the same warnings. I presumed you added the path to the Crystax NDK into your buildozer.spec. Could you please share with us your buildozer.spec?

Comment: Hi @ikolim! I've added the buildozer.spec as an update to the post above! yeah i added the path into the buildozer.spec with just '~' because the files are all in my home directory